# Does Android Lint cache old results someplace, and if so, how do I clear it?

Tags: android, android-lint

I've been cleaning up Lint warnings on my Android project, but some of them seem to persist even after I've fixed them.

For example, I got this warning:

`Use android.util.FloatMath#sqrt() instead of java.lang.Math#sqrt to avoid argument float to double conversion`

Hey, good to know.  I learned something.  So I correct the error (and I tried both converting my math to use `double` and changing `Math` for `FloatMath`) and rerun my Lint report.  The warning still appears!  What's more, the little code snip that appears in the HTML report is of the same line as before, but since I moved some code around, what's displayed is no longer relevant.  So it seems like Lint is caching the results of the previous runs somehow, but I haven't figured out how to clear that out.

I'm using command-line Lint and generating an HTML report from the results, if that's relevant.  I'm using the following command, which outputs a multi-file HTML report in the `lint_report` directory and scans the Android project in `project_directory`.

```
$ lint --html lint_report/ project_directory/
```

Can I clear out old results for Android Lint somehow, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that Android Lint uses the compiled class files to do its reporting.  The answer is simply to rebuild the app before running the Lint report.

Answer (score 1):

**In Eclipse:**

*First*

Right click on project > Android Tools > Clear Lint Markers

*Then*

Right click on project > Android Tools > Run Lint: Check for Common Errors

**Command Line:** (Following the example above)

*First*

```
rm -rf ./project_directory/lint_report
```

*Then*

Run Lint again

Comment: This would be helpful if I were running Eclipse!  My IDE is IntelliJ IDEA and in any case, I'm running my report from the command line.  I've edited my question to make this fact more obvious.

Comment: Tried that, and it didn't work.  I even put the report in a freshly created directory that didn't exist before.  The timestamps at the top of the reports always got updated, and it's not like a JUnit report where zillions of little XML files get aggregated.  It's just one file per project.